# How to return search for records in T-SQL that contain all words in input string?

Tags: sql, t-sql

For example: If the database contains

```
ID  Name           Year  Place of Birth
1   John           1989  Miami
2   Steven         2004  Orlando
3   Cassandra      1990  Chicago
4   John           2000  Orlando 
5   Elizabeth      1989  Houston
```

Searching for `John 1989` should return row 1 only.

Comment: I would suggest you input the search parameters separately for each field.  You wouldn't want "Jack" to match "Jacksonville" or "Peter" to match "St. Petersburg".

Comment: Split on client-side, then pass the parameters for the correct columns.

Comment: According to our Business specs, we have drop downs for each field but also need to have the ability to search via a single search box input.

Edit: In my original schema, the chance of overlapping is low though not non-existent. Even if an overlap occurs, it wouldn't negatively affect our expected search results much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about WHERE clause?

```
SELECT [ID], [Name], [Year], [Place of Birth]
FROM YourTable
WHERE Name = 'John' AND Year = 1989
```

Or you want stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_search
@Name NVARCHAR(100),
@Year INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT [ID], [Name], [Year], [Place of Birth] 
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE Name = @Name AND Year = @Year
END
```

So you can search in following:

```
EXECUTE sp_search 'John', 1989
```

Comment: Just to be absolutely pedantic, also only use SELECT * if you absolutely require all columns to be returned, just to save on performance where possible.

Comment: No, he wants to pass `John 1989` as a single parameter and find records where the name is 'John' and the year is '1989'. So he wants to split on space.

Comment: As Tim said, the  whole input will be a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First replace spaces in your input with `%` and then you can do something like:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(1000) = REPLACE(@yourInput, ' ', '%')

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),Name) + 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),Year) + 
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),[Place of Birth]) LIKE '%' + @input + '%'
```

This won't be super efficient as it is

Comment: We need to implement this on two sites. One of them is a smaller site with about 100,000 records, while the other is a new one with potential to have millions of records. Also, the input can be in any order, like John 1989 or 1989 John.

Comment: Then my answer is rubbish, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

### My Version of Your Table

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(10),[Year] INT, [Place of Birth] VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  (1,'John',1989,'Miami'),
        (2,'Steven',2004,'Orlando'),
        (3,'Cassandra',1990,'Chicago'),
        (4,'John',2000,'Orlando'),
        (5,'Elizabeth',1989,'Houston');
```

### Actual Query

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(100) = 'John 1989',
        @word1 VARCHAR(100),
        @word2 VARCHAR(100),
        @word3 VARCHAR(100),
        @yr INT;

--Separate words into different variables
SELECT  @word1 = SUBSTRING(@input,0,idx1),
        @word2 = SUBSTRING(@input,idx1 + 1,idx2-idx1),
        @word3 = SUBSTRING(@input,idx2 + 1,idx3-idx2)
FROM (VALUES(@Input + '   ')) A(input)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',input,0        )) AS CA(idx1)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',input,idx1 + 1))  AS CA2(idx2)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(' ',input,idx2 + 1))  AS CA3(idx3)

SELECT @yr      = (SELECT TOP (1) word FROM (VALUES(@word1),(@word2),(@word3)) A(word) WHERE ISNUMERIC(word) = 1 AND LEN(word) != 0);
WITH CTE_strings
AS
(
    SELECT word 
    FROM (VALUES(@word1),(@word2),(@word3)) A(word)
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(word) = 0 
    AND LEN(word) != 0 --length ignores white space so only grab values with at least 1 character
)

SELECT *
FROM @yourTable
WHERE   ([Year] = @yr OR @yr IS NULL) --match year unless it's empty
        AND
        (
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE_strings) = 0 --no strings. Only year is listed
            OR
            (
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE_strings) = 1 --if one string then either name or place of birth needs to match
                AND 
                (
                    Name IN (SELECT word FROM CTE_Strings)
                OR [Place of Birth] IN (SELECT word FROM CTE_Strings)
                )
            )
            OR
            (
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE_strings) = 2 --if two strings, then both name and place of birth need to be in the list
                AND Name IN (SELECT word FROM CTE_Strings)
                AND [Place of Birth] IN (SELECT word FROM CTE_Strings)
            )
        )
```

Comment: That would only answer a specific case but it should work even for John Miami or Miami John or 1989 Miami John.

Comment: Oh. Well I might have over complicated it, but my edited code works for me. Check it out.